# ubuntu - how to automatically upload a photo to my google photo?

Tags: scripts, google, photo

I have a photo that I auto-generate, and replace every five minutes. I want to create a script to auto upload to and replace the photo on my google photo every five minutes. What is the command line to do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about changing your Google profile picture, there is no command to do so.

You would need to obtain development keys from Google, then write a program that authenticates (= logs in) to Google, and then use the [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContactPhoto) to update your photo. Not an easy task.